# IndexedDB transaction error bubbles to db.onerror event of open request but displays uncaught exception error

Tags: javascript, event-handling, indexeddb

In the onsuccess event of the `indexedDB.open` request, I have a `db.onerror` event handler, as shown in the MDN document entitled [Using IndexedDB:Opening a Database](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Opening_a_database) in the "Handling Errors" section.

In testing transaction and request errors, I noticed that in the console log an `"Uncaught exception : undefined"` when a transaction errors, even if there is a stop propagation statement in the `transaction.onerror` handler. A script line number is not given, unless there is not a stop propagation statement in the `transaction.onerror` handler and an alert statement in the `db.onerror` handler.  Then the line number of the alert statement is returned with the uncaught-exception message in the console log.

Would you please tell me what this means and if this indicates a need for improved coding?  Thank you.

Unless I am misunderstanding something, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47584346/indexeddb-do-errors-bubble-all-the-way-to-idbopendbrequest) question appears to state that the transaction.onerror event should not bubble to the db.onerror in the open request. Please explain.

Thank you.

**ADDITION**
Added two blocks of code below. One opens the database and the other is a transaction to write to an object store of the database. If the transaction fails, the transaction.onerror event bubbles to the db.onerror event withing the req.onsuccess event of the open function.  Whether or not this is prevented, there is still an uncaught exception error as described above.

Please note that the unusual code in the pop_db function regarding errors is there because if the try/catch fails and the transaction is manually aborted, all the req.onerror events will fire for every individual request in the transaction and this was causing a "too much recursion" error, because each of those req.onerror events was triggering the transaction.onerror event.

Thank you.

```
  DB.open_db = ( o ) =>
    { 
      return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
        {
          // Request to open database.
          let old_v,
              req = o.version ? indexedDB.open( DB.name, o.version ) : indexedDB.open( DB.name );

          req.onerror = ( event ) => { }; // close onerror

          req.onsuccess = ( event ) =>
            { 
               DB.base = req.result;
               let db = DB.base;

               db.onerror = ( event ) =>
                 {
                   /*
                     Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests.
                     Transaction.onerror events bubble here if propagation not stopped.
                   */ 

                    alert( 'Database error: ' + event.target.error + '.' ); 
                    console.log( 'db.onerror event => Database error: ' + event.target.error + '.' );
                 }; // close onerror

               resolve( ' ... ' );

            }; // close onsuccess

          req.onupgradeneeded = ( event ) => 
            {  
               // Save the IDBDatabase interface. 
               DB.base = event.target.result;
               let db = DB.base;
               /* 
                 Is a db.onerror needed, here, as seen in some of the MDN working examples? 
                 It appears that:
                   1. An error within onupgradeneeded triggers the req.onerror event.
                   2  A db.onerror function within onupgradeneeded doesn't fire at all but goes straight to req.onerror.
               */

               old_v = event.oldVersion;
               if ( old_v < 1 )
                 // Brand new database needs all objectStores created.
                 {
                    db.createObjectStore( "data" ); 
                 }
               else 
                 {
                   // Upgrade to existing database required/requested.                                     
                 }; //  end if old_v
            }; // close onupgradeneeded

        } ); // close new promise

      }; // close DB.open
```

```
      DB.pop_db = ( o ) =>  // ( os, data, op )

        { 
          /* 
             A note about transaction and request events. Every request.onerror event handler, in turn, fires the transaction.onerror event handler.
             This was causing "too much recursion" errors. Coded it this way in order to track the key and question numbers to test against other data.
             Coded such that the first request.onerror bubbles and then the first statement of the transaction.onerror event handler sets the condition that stops
             the propogation of all further request.onerror events that subsequently fire as a result of aborting the transaction due to bad data. 
             Therefore, the transaction.onerror event is fired only once. 
             If an individual request errors the transaction will complete but the program won't continue. So, need req.onerror.
          */

          return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
            {
              let t = DB.base.transaction( [ o.os ], 'readwrite' ),
                  s = t.objectStore( o.os ),
                  req, d;

              DB.pop_db.error = false;

              t.oncomplete = ( e ) =>
                {
                  resolve();
                }; // close t.oncomplete

              t.onerror = ( e ) =>
                {
                  //e.stopPropagation(); // Stop propagation up to the database error level in the database open block.
                  DB.pop_db.error = true;
                  reject();
                }; // close t.onerror


              t.onabort = ( e ) =>
                {
                  console.log( 'Transaction aborted : ' + e.target.error );
                }; // close t.onabort

             for ( d of o.data )
               { 
                try
                 { ... }
                catch(e)
                 { t.abort(); break; }

                 req = s[ o.op ]( d );
                 req.k = d.key; 
                 req.n = d.nbr;

                 req.onsuccess = function( e )
                   {
                     if ( !DB.pop_db.error )
                       {
                         console.log( 'Success at k = ' + this.k + ', nbr = ' + this.n + '.' );
                       }; // end if
                   }; // close req.onsuccess

                 req.onerror = function( e ) 
                   { 
                     /*
                        When a transaction is rolled back/aborted, every request's error event is fired and propagates up to transaction.onerror and causes a "too much recursion" error.
                        Thus, let it propagate once and, within transaction.onerror, set error to true.
                     */

                     console.log( 'Request.onerror fired. Error = ' + e.target.error + ' k = ' + this.k + ', n = ' + this.n );

                     if ( DB.pop_db.error )
                       {
                         e.stopPropagation();
                         console.log( 'Stopping propagation' );
                       }; // end if

                   }; // close req.onerror

               }; // next d

         }); //  close promise

     }; // close DB.pop_db
```

Comment: Please include a small section of relevant code

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I have added some code.